# How can I make this script to kill Rails processes work better?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell

On my OS X development machine, sometimes I start a Rails server and due to an error or mishap I get back the prompt but the server is still running.

It happens often enough that I wrote a shell script to handle it...

`~/bin/krr_kill_rails_processes.sh`

```
#/bin/bash

echo "Rails processes:"
ps aux | grep -ie rails | awk '{print}'
ps aux | grep -ie rails | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

It works, but it's messy...

```
$ krr_kill_rails_processes.sh 
Rails processes:
jimpie           76575   0.0  0.0  2432768    632 s002  S+    4:46PM   0:00.00 grep -ie rails
jimpie           76573   0.0  0.0  2433432    968 s002  S+    4:46PM   0:00.00 sh /Users jimpie/bin/krr_kill_rails_processes.sh jimpie           76426   0.0  0.6  3140040  95144 s001  S+    4:42PM   0:04.71 /Users jimpie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby     script/rails s
kill: 76578: No such process
[1]    76573 killed     krr_kill_rails_processes.sh
```

How can I improve it so that...

- It doesn't find and kill itself.
- It doesn't find and kill the grep command.
- It doesn't emit that "No such process" error.

(Any other suggested improvements...)

---

In case it's relevant, here's the output when I start the Rails server...

```
$ bundle exec rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.9 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the various suggestions.

Turns out my OS X came with `pkill`, but it isn't working for me...

```
$ ps aux | grep -e rails  
jimpie           77530   0.0  0.7  3178332 122492   ??  S    Sun05PM   0:35.54 /Users/jimpie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby     script/rails s
jimpie           83891   0.0  0.0  2432768    608 s000  R+    1:23PM   0:00.00 grep -e rails

$ pkill rails

$ ps aux | grep -e rails
jimpie           77530   0.0  0.7  3178332 122492   ??  S    Sun05PM   0:35.55 /Users/jimpie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby     script/rails s
jimpie           83906   0.0  0.0  2432768    624 s000  R+    1:23PM   0:00.00 grep -e rails

$ pkill -9 rails

$ ps aux | grep -e rails
jimpie           77530   0.0  0.7  3178332 122492   ??  S    Sun05PM   0:35.55 /Users/jimpie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby     script/rails s
jimpie           83923   0.0  0.0  2432768    612 s000  R+    1:23PM   0:00.00 grep -e rails

$ pkill -9f rails       
pkill: illegal option -- 9
usage: pkill [-signal] [-ILfilnovx] [-F pidfile] [-G gid]
             [-P ppid] [-U uid] [-g pgrp]
             [-t tty] [-u euid] pattern ...
```

For future ref, eventually discovered grep's `-v` option and worked out a script that does what I want.

`~/bin/krr_kill_rails_processes.sh`

```
#/bin/bash

echo "Killing Rails processes..."
ps aux | grep -ie rails | grep -v 'grep' | grep -v 'krr' | awk '{print}'
ps aux | grep -ie rails | grep -v 'grep' | grep -v 'krr' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 3):

If the intent is to kill only the process for one rails project, you can kill the rails server using the process-id in the `tmp/pids/server.pid` file:

```
[ -f "<project-dir>/tmp/pids/server.pid" ] && kill -9 `cat "<project-dir>/tmp/pids/server.pid`"
```

If you want to use your `grep` approach, then you can use this trick to prevent the grep command from showing up in the grep results :

```
ps aux | grep "[r]ails"
```

Comment: Why is the `pid` way better?

Answer (score 1):

- It doesn't find and kill the grep command.

instead of `grep -ie rails`, you can use `grep -ie [r]ails`

```
#/bin/bash

echo "Rails processes:"
ps aux | grep -ie [r]ails | awk '{print}'
ps aux | grep -ie [r]ails | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

If you os has `pkill`, you can use `pkill -9f rails` to kill rails, no need script
for more details, see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/pkill.1.html

Comment: pkill -9f rails rails on OSX

Answer (score 1):

Instead of start and kill rails in `Shell`, I suggest you to take a look at [Pow](http://pow.cx). No configuration, no maintenance required. All you need is put a symbolic link inside .pow folder.  And your can access "your_project_name.dev" (no hosts change required)

even better, there is a small GUI application available for you to manage it. [Anvil](http://anvilformac.com)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Largely from http://soziotechnischemassnahmen.blogspot.com/2010/03/poor-mans-pgrep-on-mac-os-x.html

Try

```
ps -axo pid,command | awk '$NF == "script/rails" {print $1}' | xargs kill
```

Also, strongly agree with their suggestion of installing proctools and just doing `pkill rails`.

e.g.

```
> cat input.txt
76575 grep
76573 /Users jimpie/bin/krr_kill_rails_processes.sh
76426 /Users jimpie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby     script/rails
> awk '$NF == "script/rails" {print $1}' input.txt
76426
```